# If is cell empty, get data function return / (slash)

Tags: vba, excel

Im getting data from specific cells in closed workbooks but if the cell is empty it gets me empty cell.  I need to improve get data function so if the cell from which i will be geting data is empty, then get data function return "/" or other character.

Thank you very much!

```
Sub Recurse()
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder, mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim myFile As File
Dim sPath$: sPath = "C:\Users\Marek\Desktop\skuska\"
Dim R$
R = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange), "|")
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
    DoEvents
    If Not (InStr(1, R, myFile.Path) > 0) Then
        GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "A1:A2",     Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)), True, False
        GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "B1:B2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)), True, False
        GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "C1:C2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)), True, False
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = myFile.Path
        R = R & myFile.Path & "|"
    End If
Next
Next
 Set FSO = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set mySubFolder = Nothing
Set myFile = Nothing
```

End Sub

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
               SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean,     UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long

' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    End If
End If

If SourceSheet = "" Then
    ' workbook level name
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then

    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
End If

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
       vbExclamation, "Error"
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to loop through the data you've recieved cell by cell.. After the data has been pasted, use a loop to go through the target range (range of data on excel sheet) with a loop. so like:

```
for i = TargetRangeStartRow to numRowsInTargetRange
    for j = TargetRangeStartCol to numColsInTargetRange
        if Cells(i,j).formulaR1C1 = "" then
            Cells(i,j).formulaR1C1 = "/"
        end if
    next
next
```

where obviously you'd need to use the first row in the target source, and the first column, and you'll need to get the number of rows and column in the target range as well. I say to use target range because that (Im assuming) is the range where the data is being pasted into Excel.

From Excel there isn't much of a way (I don't think?) to look at access and see beforehand if any of the data is missing. Regardless you'd still need to loop through the entire thing so it's just as well you do that after the data is pasted into Excel sheet.

Comment: This looks good. But my problem is that i need to do this loop after every new row been added. And everytime it needs to be the last row of the table.  I edit the code and add the recurse function. I think the loop could be after this line: R = R & myFile.Path & "|" . I need to check the last row that has been added.